# Макрос VBA. копирование изменяемого диапазона данных

Tags: excel, vba

Есть эксель файл "донор", расположен по пути "путь к донору". Обновляется ежедневно, разное кол-во строк данных там каждый день. Все на одном листе.
Есть эксель файл "остатки", расположен по пути "путь к остаткам". Там хранится все что копируется ежедневно из донора руками, каждый раз добавляя вниз данные.

Нужен макрос (предполагаю запускать его из другого файла) который будет копировать из донора с A5 по R5, а строк столько сколько есть с данными (если такое возможно). Вставлять полученное на лист "данные", в ячейку B, строка первая пустая, в конце данных. Слева от того что будет вставлено (А столбец) нужна текущая дата. Справа от вставленного (Т столбец) сумма строки с С по S (то что скопировано кроме первого столбца, там текст). И нужно нажимать данные - обновить все (обновляет данные в сводной). Сохранить, закрыть (если файл вообще открываться будет)

Comment: Нужен макрос? пишите. Будут КОНКРЕТНЫЕ проблемы - приходите, поможем.

Comment: конкретная проблема и есть в том, что я не знаю как написать макрос =)

Comment: Нет вопроса, есть ТЗ - сделать задачу полностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:
Создай макрос

```
    // Читаем другой файл:
    Dim WB As Workbook  
    Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\...\Рабочий стол\Книга4.xlsx", Password:="123321")  

    Sheet1 = WB.Sheets("Лист1")

    // Обрабатываем диапазон
    For Counter = 1 To 20 
     Set curCell = Sheet1.Cells(Counter, 3) 
     // curCell.Value  - значение ячейки из другого файла вставляем куда надо
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ЛистКудаВставляем").Cells(Строка, Колонка).Value = curCell.Value
    Next Counter

    WB.Close
```

Comment: как объяснить экселю, что в доноре надо брать данные начиная с А5? Counter это что? и как объяснить, что вставлять нужно в первую пустую ячейку в столбце B?

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то выдаёт ошибку 438? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться:

```
'Читаем другой файл:
Sub DonRec()
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\..\Donor .xlsx")
Sheet1 = WB.Sheets("Don") 'Здесь ошибка
'Обрабатываем диапазон
For Counter = 1 To 20
Set curCell = Sheet1.Cells(Counter, 3)
'curCell.Value  - Значение ячейки из другого файла вставляем куда надо
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ЛистКудаВставляем").Cells(Строка, Колонка).Value = curCell.Value
Next Counter
WB.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Точно не на строке `Set WB`?  Путь указан правильно? `Sheet1` -присваиваете объект переменной, но `Set` отсутствует. И не нужно давать переменным зарезервированные имена. Например: *Set sht = WB.Sheets("Don")*

Comment: была такая же ошибка, добавил сет, помогло. теперь ошибка subscript out of range. Здесь ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1").Cells(5, 1).Value = curCell.Value. что не так?